# K-Nearest Neighbours Error - What is X meant to represent?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

The following code generates the error that 'X' is not defined:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

A = np.array([[3.1, 2.3], [2.3, 4.2], [3.9, 3.5], [3.7, 6.4], [4.8, 1.9], 
             [8.3, 3.1], [5.2, 7.5], [4.8, 4.7], [3.5, 5.1], [4.4, 2.9],])

k = 3

test_data = [3.3, 2.9]

plt.figure()
plt.title('Input data')
plt.scatter(A[:,0], A[:,1], marker = 'o', s = 100, color = 'black')
plt.show()

knn_model = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors = k, algorithm = 'auto').fit(X)
distances, indices = knn_model.kneighbors([test_data])

print("\nK Nearest Neighbors:")
for rank, index in enumerate(indices[0][:k], start = 1):
   print(str(rank) + " is", A[index])

plt.figure()
plt.title('Nearest neighbors')
plt.scatter(A[:, 0], X[:, 1], marker = 'o', s = 100, color = 'k')
plt.scatter(A[indices][0][:][:, 0], A[indices][0][:][:, 1],
   marker = 'o', s = 250, color = 'k', facecolors = 'none')
plt.scatter(test_data[0], test_data[1],
   marker = 'x', s = 100, color = 'k')
plt.show()
```

However, the error disappears when replacing 'X' with 'A'. From what I understand, X is meant to be the training data - is this correct, and if so, what should I use for X?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is a typo and it should say A instead of X.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, X should be the independent variable(s), and y is the dependent variable, right.

In research, variables are any characteristics that can take on different values, such as height, age, species, or exam score.

In scientific research, we often want to study the effect of one variable on another one. For example, you might want to test whether students who spend more time studying get better exam scores.

The variables in a study of a cause-and-effect relationship are called the independent and dependent variables.

```
The independent variable is the cause. Its value is independent of other variables in your study.
The dependent variable is the effect. Its value depends on changes in the independent variable.
```

[image]

Here is some generic code to illustrate the point.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\your_path_here\\classified_data.csv",index_col=0)
df.head()

df.info()

df.describe()

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()


scaler.fit(df.drop('TARGET CLASS',axis=1))
scaled_features = scaler.transform(df.drop('TARGET CLASS',axis=1))


df_feat = pd.DataFrame(scaled_features,columns=df.columns[:-1])
df_feat.head()


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = df_feat
y = df['TARGET CLASS']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(scaled_features,df['TARGET CLASS'], test_size=0.50, random_state=101)


from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
knn.fit(X_train,y_train)


KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=1, p=2,
           weights='uniform')


pred = knn.predict(X_test)


from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix
conf_mat=confusion_matrix(y_test,pred)
print(conf_mat)


print(classification_report(y_test,pred))
```

Result:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.88      0.90      0.89       250
           1       0.90      0.87      0.89       250

    accuracy                           0.89       500
   macro avg       0.89      0.89      0.89       500
weighted avg       0.89      0.89      0.89       500
```

You can download the sample data from this link.

https://www.kaggle.com/shubh247/simple-way-handle-classified-data-using-knn?select=Classified+Data